# nwdiag of home lan, is it whack?

Tags: networking, lan, subnet, vlan

Are there problems I can avoid by subnetting differently? I'm setting up a modest home lan, and I want to know if I missed anything critical or if there's a simpler way to subnet with given requirements. My requirements are: hardware nodes, low power (except workstation), gigabyte networking, except lightweight www services, extremely configurable, separate vlans/subnets for fw, vpn, dmz, lan, and wifi.

link to nwdiag png output:
https://postimg.cc/HcGhPkw7

Note: RPI is a bottleneck at wifi segment and will be replaced soon.

Q: Should the UPS be placed on the vpn network segment for easier remote power-management options or is this a security risk?

If you're curious how I made the image, it's nwdiag -- very cool program that has been around for a little while (oreilly books etc).

and here is the "source code":

```
nwdiag {

inet[shape = "cloud"];

  inet -- nap;   nap -- noc;

  network comcast {
    address = "71.-.-.-/16";
    noc;
    edge;   }

  edge -- modem;   modem[address="71.-.-.-,SB6141"];   modem -- router;

group isp {   color = "#ccddff";   noc edge; }

  network fw {
    address="10.12.176.0/28";
    router [address="10.1.176.1,Soekris net6501/npf"];
    dmz[address="10.12.176.2, Cisco Catalyst 1"];
    lan[address="10.12.176.3, Cisco Catalyst 2"];
    vpn[address="10.12.176.4,apu2e4 / NetBSD,racoon vpn"];   }

  network vpn {
    address="10.84.37.176/30"
    vpn[address="10.84.37.177"];
    workstation [address="10.84.37.178,HP z840 / Xen"];   }

  network lan {
    address="192.168.42.0/28"
    lan[address="192.168.42.1"];
    printer[address="192.168.42.2,HP 4250tn"]
    wap[address="192.168.42.3,RPI3B+/ath9k,NetBSD"];
    ups[address="192.168.42.4,Eaton 9100"];

  }

  network dmz {
    address="172.16.93.11/28";
    dmz[address="172.16.93.8"];
    dns1[address="172.16.93.9,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];
    dns2[address="172.16.93.10,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];
    web[address="172.16.93.11,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];   }

  network wifi {
    address="192.168.221.1/28";
    wap[address="192.168.221.1"];
    iphone1[address=".dhcp"];
    iphone2[address=".dhcp"];
    ipad[address=".dhcp"];
    macbookair[address=".dhcp"];   }

}
```

---

### UPDATE

Okay, so I've been reading up a bit and here are my modifications to the network (and the code). What I think I need to do for *maximum security* (a requirement I accidentally omitted in my OP) is have each switch and router on a /30, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement that because I also need more than one or two hosts on most network segments.

Also, I use three different private addressing schemes to be able to tell them apart easily in tcpdump or similar. I truly don't know how much I'm going to regret this in the future (perhaps someone could tell me their experience with that).

If my vpn addressing looks messy it's on purpose, to defeat guess attacks, i.e., 192.168.1.1 .2 .3 .4, easily guessed, whereas 10.84.37.178, not so much. If somebody tells me different and gives me a compelling reason to do so I will change it. That's why I'm here!

Anyway, this is my best try and link to the updated png: https://postimg.cc/qzy774xB

```
nwdiag {

isp[shape = "cloud"];

  isp -- modem;
  modem;
  modem -- fw-1;

  network fw {
    address="10.12.176.0/30";
    fw-1 [address="10.12.176.1,Soekris net6501/npf"];
    vpn-1[address="10.13.176.1,apu2e4 / NetBSD,racoon vpn"];
    dmz-1[address="10.14.176.1, Catalyst 1"];
    lan-1[address="10.15.176.1, Catalyst 2"];
    }


  network vpn {
    address="10.84.37.176/30";
    vpn-1[address="10.84.37.177"];
    workstation [address="10.84.37.178,HP z840 / Xen"];
  }


  network dmz {
    address="172.16.93.11/28";
    dmz-1[address="172.16.93.8"];
    dns-1[address="172.16.93.9,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];
    dns-2[address="172.16.93.10,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];
    web-1[address="172.16.93.11,BeagleBone Black / Minix3"];
  }

  network lan {
    address="192.168.42.0/28"
    lan-1[address="192.168.42.1"];
    wap-1[address="192.168.42.3,RPI3B+/ath9k,NetBSD"];
    lp-1[address="192.168.42.2,HP 4250tn"]
    ups-1[address="192.168.42.4,Eaton 9100"];
  }

  network wifi {
    address="192.168.221.1/28";
    wap-1[address="192.168.221.1"];
    iphone-1[address=".dhcp"];
    iphone-2[address=".dhcp"];
    ipad[address=".dhcp"];
    macbookair[address=".dhcp"];
  }

}
```

Comment: What's up with the completely different network numbers everywhere?

Comment: I am using network segmentation for security purposes and secondly for congestion purposes, each type of traffic has it's own network essentially. I do this using a technique called subnetting. I simply want to know if I'm doing it properly as I am not a professional -- a second pair of eyes on it.

Comment: That didn't really answer the question -- why is it necessary for some network numbers to be from the 10.x range, some from the 192.168 range, and then some from 172.16? Your numbering scheme looks completely random and a bit messy.

Comment: Ah! I thought it would be good to tell them apart instantly with simple tools like tcpdump, but maybe that is unnecessarily complicating it. Also, I have a creeping suspicion that I will have to do some math in octal (or some kind of mental gymnastics) at some point and the different addresses would make it ridiculous. What say you?